# kotlin - filter MutableList with append other items in the end of list

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

Actually I want to sort my list in this way:
I have a mutableList like this

```
noteList = mutableListOf<NoteDataHolder>().apply {
        notes.forEach {
            add(NoteDataHolder(it))
        }
}
```

Imagin `NoteDataHolder` has `Id` and I want to sort my list by this `Id`

My list like this: `[ {id=1}, {id=2}, {id=3}, {id=4} ]`

when I filter my list like this:`noteList.filter { it.note?.bookId == 4 }`

I receive only `[ {id=4} ]`

finally, I want to get all item after `item4` like this `[ {id=4}, {id=1}, {id=2}, {id=3} ]`

Comment: What about `noteList.filter { it.note?.bookId >= 4 }`? Does that give you the desired output?

Comment: @deHaar I want all items but it removes under 4

Comment: OK, is it desired to get the ids less or equal 4 then? Like `noteList.filter { it.note?.bookId <= 4 }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
fun reorderItems(input: List<NoteDataHolder>, predicate: (NoteDataHolder) -> Boolean): List<NoteDataHolder>{
    val matched = input.filter(predicate)
    val unmatched = input.filterNot(predicate)

    return matched + unmatched
}
```

For use:

```
noteList = reorderItems (noteList!!) {it.note?.bookId == 4}
```